# the splice method giving unknown results

Tags: javascript

i am trying to check what items are in array.
this is my code

```
var fruits=['banana','orange','lemon'];
fruits.splice(0,1,'apple');
for (i=0;i<=fruit.length;i++)
{
alert('The fruits are' + fruits[i]);
};
```

Somehow it's not Working.
please tell me where i am doing wrong.
thanks.

Comment: please add s after fruit in for loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you mistakenly added `fruit.length` or you have written code like this?

Answer (score 0):

```
syntax;-
array.splice(index,howmany,item1,.....,itemX)
index->positon from/to u want to ad and remove items
howmany->how many item u want add/remove
item->item list(for more than pne seprate it by comma)
```

also:-
    please add s after fruit in for loop

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: please see above modified code